# jquery with Google Analytics href

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess, google-analytics

So I had this working last week and I have not changed any code or anything at all.

I have the google analytics javascript file being loaded with the .htaccess file so that it is always being used for all pages etc. Worked just fine before when I was testing the functions last week.

All of a sudden, only the last "else if" function works which is /cart/ for the url. Makes no sense to me.

Before you ask, I used jquery instead of $ because by default, jquery is not loaded/on so $ gives errors.

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

// requires jQuery
+function (ga){
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
if(window.location.href.indexOf("flat-model-specs/") > -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'Models',
    'eventAction': 'click',
    'eventLabel': 'Flat Model Specs',
    'transport': 'beacon'
    });
    }
if(window.location.href.indexOf("utility-model-specs/") > -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'Models',
    'eventAction': 'click',
    'eventLabel': 'Utility Model Specs',
    'transport': 'beacon'
    });
    }
else if(window.location.href.indexOf("goose-model-specs/") > -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'Models',
    'eventAction': 'click',
    'eventLabel': 'Goose Model Specs',
    'transport': 'beacon'
    });
    }
else if(window.location.href.indexOf("enclosed-model-specs/") > -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'Models',
    'eventAction': 'click',
    'eventLabel': 'Enclosed Model Specs',
    'transport': 'beacon'
    });
    }
else if(window.location.href.indexOf("dock-height/") > -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'Models',
    'eventAction': 'click',
    'eventLabel': 'Dock Height',
    'transport': 'beacon'
    });
    }
else if(window.location.href.indexOf("specs/") > -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'Models',
    'eventAction': 'click',
    'eventLabel': 'Specs',
    'transport': 'beacon'
    });
    }
else if(window.location.href.indexOf("features/") > -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'Features',
    'eventAction': 'click',
    'eventLabel': 'Features Page',
    'transport': 'beacon'
    });
    }
else if(window.location.href.indexOf("air-or-rubber-suspension/") > -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'Features',
    'eventAction': 'click',
    'eventLabel': 'Air or Rubber Suspension Page',
    'transport': 'beacon'
    });
    }
else if(window.location.href.indexOf("accessories/") > -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'Accessories',
    'eventAction': 'click',
    'eventLabel': 'Accessories Page',
    'transport': 'beacon'
    });
    }
else if(window.location.href.indexOf("product/battery/") > -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'Product',
    'eventAction': 'click',
    'eventLabel': 'Battery',
    'transport': 'beacon'
    });
    }
else if(window.location.href.indexOf("video-portfolio/") > -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'Videos',
    'eventAction': 'click',
    'eventLabel': 'Video Page',
    'transport': 'beacon'
    });
    }
else if(window.location.href.indexOf("financing/") > -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'Financing',
    'eventAction': 'click',
    'eventLabel': 'Financing Page',
    'transport': 'beacon'
    });
    }
else if(window.location.href.indexOf("frequently-asked-questions/") > -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'Resources',
    'eventAction': 'click',
    'eventLabel': 'FAQ Page',
    'transport': 'beacon'
    });
    }
else if(window.location.href.indexOf("brochure/") > -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'Resources',
    'eventAction': 'click',
    'eventLabel': 'Brochure Page',
    'transport': 'beacon'
    });
    }
else if(window.location.href.indexOf("become-a-dealer/") > -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'Resources',
    'eventAction': 'click',
    'eventLabel': 'Become a Dealer Page',
    'transport': 'beacon'
    });
    }
else if(window.location.href.indexOf("about-us/") > -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'About Us',
    'eventAction': 'click',
    'eventLabel': 'About Us Page',
    'transport': 'beacon'
    });
    }
else if(window.location.href.indexOf("contact-us/") > -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'Contact Us',
    'eventAction': 'click',
    'eventLabel': 'Contact Us Page',
    'transport': 'beacon'
    });
    }
else if(window.location.href.indexOf("shop/") > -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'Shop',
    'eventAction': 'click',
    'eventLabel': 'Shopping Page',
    'transport': 'beacon'
    });
    }
else if(window.location.href.indexOf("cart/") > -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'Cart',
    'eventAction': 'click',
    'eventLabel': 'Shopping Cart Page',
    'transport': 'beacon'
    });
    }
});
}

(function (a,b,c){
if(a === 'send'){
    window.ga('send',b,c)
}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it was due to Wordpress only allowing this script to run if I were logged into the admin panel of wordpress. I had to whitelist the javascript file in wordpress for it to work. Wordpress is a joke.